# Obtener item aleatorio de una lista de objetos React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, usestate

estoy practicando con React JS.
Tengo una lista de objetos, quiero obtener un elemento aleatorio de la lista y mostrarlo por jsx.

El tema es que obtengo el objecto aleatorio en la funcion GetObject, pero no logro guardarlo correctamente en el state object y a su vez no l o puedo mostrar por jsx. Alguien sabe como l o podria solucionar?

```
const SurpriseJs = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [object, setObject] = useState([]);

  const GetList = () => {
    //obtengo lista de objetos desde un mock
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return resolve(MoviesMock);
      }, 2000);
    });
  };
  //lo guardo en state list
  useEffect(() => {
    GetList().then((list) => {
      setList(list);
    });
  }, []);
  //cuando se guarda en list, que ejecute GetObject
  useEffect(() => {
    GetObject();
  }, [list]);

  // ACA ESTA EL ERROR obtengo elemento aleatorio y lo guardo en state, pero se guarda mal y no me deja mostrar
  const GetObject = () => {
    let objects = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];

    setObject({ objects });
  };

  console.log('objectt', object);
  // <Item data={object} key={object.id}>
  return (
    <div className="item-container">
      <img src={object.img} />
      <p style={{ color: 'white' }}>{object.category}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SurpriseJs;
```

Comment: prueba con `setObject(objects)` (sin las `{ }`)

Comment: si pongo sin  no me guarda el objeto. cuando intento accederlo me tira error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')

Comment: si pongo sin  no me guarda el objeto. cuando intento accederlo me tira error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img'). 
setObject({ objects }) guardandolo asi me guarda un objeto dentro de un objeto
seria object={objects:{id:1,title:"ok"}}
El tema que en cuando quiero acceder a las propiedades de objects(el objeto adentro) no me deja, me tira undefined. 
Para acceder intento console.log(object.objects.id)
EN JS vainilla si deja

Comment: que valor contiene `MoviesMock`? Probablemente el error esté en que no estas esperando a `object` tenga un valor antes de acceder a su propiedad `img`. si haces `{ object && <img src={object.img} /> }`?